# Induced Topology

Tags: general-topology

A Topology induced from a family of functions $f_{s}$ , where $s \in S$ is called the smallest with respect of inclusion of topology, where all $f_{s}$ are continous .
Show that $\ B = \{ \bigcap f_{s_{i}}^{-1} (V_{s_{i}} ) \ : s_{i}, \ldots, s_{k} \in  S , V_{s_{i}} \in \tau_{s_{i} } \} $  
a) is a base for a topology

 
b) $\tau $ appointed by $B$ is the smallest

I know a property , that B is a base if it satisfies two conditions: 
$\forall_{x_{0} \in X} \ \exists_{U \in \mathcal{B}}: \ x_{0} \in U$

$\forall_{U_{1},U_{2} \in \mathcal{B}} \ \forall_{x_{0} \in U_{1}\cap U_{2}} \ \exists_{V \in B}: \ x_{0} \in V \subseteq U_{1} \cap U_{2}$ 
And by defintion : A base $B$ of a topological space $X$ is a collection of open sets such that every open set can be written as a union of elements of $B$.
How to start this proof ?

Comment: @Sou燈馬想 i don't know how to start this proof

Comment: B is closed under finite intersections so the second condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer a), and just leave that the generated topology from a basis is the intersection of all topologies containing the basis, hence minimality. (This you may prove)

Let $f_s : X \to Y_s$ be your family of functions indexed by $s\in S$, and let $Y_s$ equipped with the topology $\tau_s$. Since $Y_s \in \tau_s$ for every $s$, by definition of a topology, then $X = f_s^{-1}(Y_s) \in B$. Then for any $x \in X$ there is a basis element containing it, namely $X$. Now suppose $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ where $B_1,B_2 \in B$. Then there are indices $s_1, \dots, s_k, t_1, \dots, t_l \in S$ and sets $U_{s_i} \in \tau_{s_i}, U_{t_j} \in \tau_{t_j}$ for every $i = 1, \dots, k$ and $j = 1, \dots, l$, such that $B_1 = \bigcap_{i=1}^k f_{s_i}^{-1}(U_{s_i})$ and $B_2 = \bigcap_{j=1}^l f_{t_j}^{-1}(U_{t_j})$: In plainer English, the sets are intersections of preimages, by definition of being basis elements. It should be clear that $B_1 \cap B_2 \in B$, since it is a finite intersection of sets of the required form for belonging in $B$. Thus $B$ is a basis for a topology.